# Java - Use of Type-specifc Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, architecture, polymorphism

Consider the following: say we have an `IRestaurant` and an `IBooking` interface.

We then have the following interface function:

```
interface IBooking {
  void reserve(IRestaurant restaurant);
}
```

However, business requirements dictate a booking service in a country could make reservations to only restaurants in the same country. Then say we have in USA:

```
class USABooking implements IBooking { ... }
class USARestaurant implements IRestaurant { ... }
```

In this case, since `reserve()` in `IBooking` takes in *any* instance of `IRestaurant`, the `USABooking` implementation would be required to check the instance of the `IRestaurant` to see if it is an instance of a `USARestaurant` and then downcast. However, we could also do this as an alternative:

```
interface IBooking<R extends IRestaurant> {
  void reserve(R restaurant);
}

class USABooking implements IBooking<USARestaurant> {
  void reserve(USARestaurant restaurant) { ... }
}
```

Is this a recommended way to go about enforcing the type limitation? In other words, is this better than performing runtime checks on the restaurant instance types? The typing approach sounds good to me, but I just want to make sure it won't "blow up" the architecture and turn out to be a misuse or abuse, since there are other interfaces that also would require such limitations (e.g. ICuisine).

Comment: Yes, it’s a good design.  (What is not a good design is starting interface names with an extra `I`.  [Here is the list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/allclasses-index.html) of all classes in Java SE;  notice that not one interface name is prefixed with `I`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative since I don't understand why there are `USABooking`  and `USARestaurant` classes:

Consider just having a `Booking` and `Restaurant` class, where `Restaurant` provides a `getCountry()` method.  Separately, to avoid a proliferation of classes, a `Booking` instance might have something like a `List<RestaurantBookingRule>` - in this case there would be a single rule that checks the country of the `Restaurant`.  For example:

```
public class Restaurant {
    private final String country;  // constructor omitted

    public String getCountry() { return country; }
}

public interface RestaurantBookingRule {
    public void validateRequest(Restaurant r);  // throws exception if the rule is broken
}

public class RequiredCountry implements BookingRule {
   private final String country;  // constructor omitted

   public void validateRequest(Restaurant r) {
       if (!r.getCountry().equals(country))
          throw ...
   }
}

public class Booking {
    private final List<RestaurantBookingRule> rules;  // constructor omitted

    public void reserve(Restaurant r) {
      rules.forEach(r -> r.validateRequest(r));
       ...
    }
}
```

then:

```
Restaurant r1 = new Restaurant("USA");
Restaurant r2 = new Restaurant("CAN");
Booking usaBooking = new Booking(List.of(new RequriedCountry("USA"));
usaBooking.reserve(r1); // ok
usaBooking.reserve(r2); // throws exception
```